# Google Analytics Send Event on Ajax Success Not Working

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, google-analytics-api

I have a Process Transaction Knockout method that returns a transaction status and depending on that status I want analytics.js event to be sent. I've used analytics-debug.js and in the console it says "Send finished" but the event never shows up in Google Analytics.

The send event works if it is before or after the ajax request but not if it is in the success or done callbacks.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ProcessTransaction',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'data',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.StatusCode == 1 || result.StatusCode == 4) {
            var subtotal = 7.95;
            var enrollmentFee = 25;
            var total = subtotal + enrollmentFee;
            ga('ec:addProduct', {
                'id': 'P12345',
                'name': 'Test Product 1',
                'category': 'Products',
                'brand': 'Brand',
                'price': subtotal,
                'quantity': 1
            });
            ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
                'id': 'T12345',
                'affiliation': 'TestSite',
                'revenue': total,
                'tax': enrollmentFee,
            });
            ga('send', 'event', 'Review', 'transaction', 'approved', total);
            $('#submitpaymentbtn').data('loading-text', 'Approved!').button('loading');
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Confirmation", new { ParticipantId = Participant.ParticipantId })';
        }
        else {
            $('#modal-error').modal();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you checking in Real-Time reports for the event? Events won't show up in Standard reports until after the data is processed, which can take anywhere of up to 24 hours.

Comment: Yes and I can get the event to show but only if it is not in the success function of the the ajax method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send event does not allow decimal for event value. Math.round(total) fixes the issue. Even thought the analytics debug says event sent, it is never accepted or logged because the value must be an integer.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Review', 'transaction', 'approved', Math.round(total));
```